# Facebook Messenger, send webview directly

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-like

So i found that the 3 ways to send webviews on facebook messenger are:
[image]

All of those solutions implies to send either a Menu, a Card or a Chat extension where the user have to click.

What im looking for is that when the user interacts with my bot *(at the moment he says "please send me the webview")*, the chat **without clicking some button** redirects the user to a webview. In this way the conversational flow its not affected by pop-up screens.

Is there a way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well define what “when the user interacts with my bot” means exactly then first. Although I doubt Facebook would actually want you to do this; it sounds like you just wanted to misuse the messenger platform to redirect the user to outside content …?

Comment: yes, maybe it creates a security hole and thats why facebook doesnt allow this kind of interactions. I just want to be sure